# Biztalk mapping with namespace prefix

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I got a requirement to produce an output messages with namespace prefix on all nodes.

Could someone please help me?

My problem is that after mapping in BizTalk, the output message has inline namespace.

For example, I expect:

```
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="http://www.domain1.com" xmlns:domain2="http://www.domain2.com">
    <domain2:element1>abc</domain2:element1>
    <ns0:element2>abc</ns0:element2>
</ns0:root>
```

But it was:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.domain1.com">
    <element1 xmlns="http://www.domain2.com">abc</element1>
    <element2 xmlns="http://www.domain1.com">abc</element2>
</root>
```

The namespace aliases ns0, domain2 are not important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these Xml are same, it does not matter if prefix is used or not as good as Xml elements belong to the namespace as per defined scheme. Its not a valid requirement to request xml with specific prefix. Even if you need to do it, use custom Xslt.

Comment: It's good practice to qualify elements with a prefix.  Some parsers might have trouble working with default namespaces, and some trading partners might require that elements be qualified.

Comment: Yes, as Dan Field said, unfortunately our customer got trouble with default namespace.

Comment: As I said earlier if u have to do it, use custom Xslt. I agree with Dan about qualifying elements with namespace, however yr both xml has qualified elements already, so I assume yr schema is correct. Having prefix just avoid declaring namespace with every element. If you validate yr second xml with yr schema it should be valid also as the first one. If yr customer insists on having prefixes them you can do it using custom Xslt. Validate yr map, it will generate Xsl file, check in output window. Use that as yr starting point. Once Dane save the Xsl file in yr project and use it in map.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ElementFormDefault` property on the target schema to `Qualified`:

[image: Qualified Property]

This property can be viewed by clicking on the `<Schema>` node in the tree for the schema in question; note it's a change to the schema, not being done in the map (despite what the image might look like):

[image: Schema node]

Comment: This is customer's schema, I cannot change it. Maybe custom xslt is an option.

Comment: Yeah, the mapping engine is going to rely on that property in the schema.  If you can't change it, custom XSLT is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many legacy parsers that rely on ns prefix. Even if it's the same thing. the solution here is to set your schema to XML type and you will have your namespace, if you have a flat file schema you have to as mentioned by Dan Field set your ElementFormDefault to Qualified, and write what you want in XSLT